# Facebook authentication returning profile name [undefined undefined] using passportJS

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, authentication, passport.js

I am using `passportJS` for facebook authentication

when requesting for profile's name in facebook strategy function

```js
user.facebook.name  = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
```

it returns the name `undefined`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR237.png)

Comment: How are you requesting the profile name?

Comment: Using passportJS function
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({

  clientID          : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
  clientSecret   : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
  callbackURL  : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
  passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass in the req from our route (lets us check if a user is logged in or not)
}, ....... }

Comment: In routes 
    app.get('/connect/facebook', passport.authorize('facebook', {
      scope : ['public_profile', 'email']
    }));

Comment: app.get('/connect/facebook/callback',
        passport.authorize('facebook', {
            successRedirect : '/profile',
            failureRedirect : '/'
        }));

Comment: did you debug "profile" or "profile.name"?